# Programmatically change the highlighted state of a UITabBarItem - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbaritem

I would like to know how to make the UITabBarItem be highlighted when I choose to do so in the program. Is this possible?

THanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change which tab is selected -- which also changes the highlight -- easily:

```
tabcontroller.selectedIndex = youNewIndexHere;
```

If your tabcontroller is in the app delegate (which is the case if you used the tab bar application template when you created your project) it would look something like this:

```
ProjectNameAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ProjectNameAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate tabcontroller].selectedIndex = youNewIndexHere;
```

Comment: thanks! In the case of the selectedIndex, what would this be? The object ID? or the Tag?

Comment: The new tab, 0 for the first tab, 1 for the second, etc. (If this works for you, please check the checkmark next to my answer.)

Comment: I don't have a tabBarController but a UITabBar, does it work in the same manner please?

Comment: UITabBar has a property called selectedItem that works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

tabbar works if you know the index and write it like this:

```
NSMutableArray *item [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[items addObject: [[[UITabBarItem alloc] initAsULike] autorelease]; <--- init as you like here

...

[tabBar setItems:items animated:FALSE];

tabBar.selectedItem = [items objectAtIndex: your_index]; <--- write your index here
[items release];
```

Comment: and ofc add the tabbar to the view and release it!

Answer (score 0):

I've got a UITabBar, created in IB but without a TabBarController. In my awakeFromNib I just initialise it to the first item like this:

```
[self.tabBar setSelectedItem:[[self.tabBar items] objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Don't forget, the UITabBarDelegate didSelectItem does not get called in this case.